# EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV) and KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS

Tags: ios7, memory-leaks, bluetooth, automatic-ref-counting

This issue is getting on my nerves. Please see the crash report and help. In iOS 6 app is working fine. I am performing some operations. After 30 operations are completed I am experiencing this crash. This number can go till 20 also or 1 also. Attaching crash log with this. All the experts please help.

```
Incident Identifier: E863E717-DE21-4BD0-A203-32E9D4648869
CrashReporter Key:   b7fe8726c57b6cc93687be0e904625ecf3813fb9
Hardware Model:      iPad2,5
Process:             mobile [3833]
Path:                
Identifier:          
Version:             
Code Type:           ARM (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2014-06-01 17:07:33.679 +0530
OS Version:          iOS 7.0.6 (11B651)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x1e2d1f28
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x38e79b26 objc_msgSend + 6
1   CoreFoundation                  0x2e618650 CFRelease + 552
2   CoreFoundation                  0x2e626702 -[__NSDictionaryI dealloc] + 114
3   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x38e89b06 objc_object::sidetable_release(bool) + 170
4   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x38e7b002 (anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) + 354
5   CoreFoundation                  0x2e61b97c _CFAutoreleasePoolPop + 12
6   Foundation                      0x2f00385c -[NSAutoreleasePool release] + 116
7   CoreFoundation                  0x2e6b3180 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 12
8   CoreFoundation                  0x2e6b264e __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 202
9   CoreFoundation                  0x2e6b0e42 __CFRunLoopRun + 618
10  CoreFoundation                  0x2e61bc22 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 518
11  CoreFoundation                  0x2e61ba06 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
12  Foundation                      0x2f0093d6 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 250
13  mobile                  0x001704d0 -[VFIPinpad waitForACK] (VFIPinpad.m:2876)
14  mobile                  0x00174cd8 -[VFIPinpad sendDataCommand:calcLRC:] (VFIPinpad.m:3716)
15  mobile                  0x0017a46a -[VFIPinpad setROSParams:threshold:target:targetPercent:] (VFIPinpad.m:4702)
16  mobile                  0x0020d5a4 -[VFIPWLm startTransaction:origAmount:finalAmount:surcharge:invoice:discount:promocode:chequeData:AVSAddress:AVSPostcode:email:refTransactionID:gpsLatitude:gpsLongitude:merchID:terminalID:allowRefundSystemByID:status:statusMsg:tranID:authCode:totalCharge:signatureRequired:voiceAuthPhone:merchantID:tipAmount:receiptData:cardScheme:] (VFIPWLm.m:2840)
17  mobile                  0x00064df0 -[MainViewController startTran] (MainViewController.m:1918)
18  mobile                  0x00077dac -[MainViewController showView] (MainViewController.m:3359)
19  mobile                  0x00084d14 -[MainViewController sc8Next] (MainViewController.m:4674)
20  UIKit                           0x30e8f70e -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 86
21  UIKit                           0x30e8f6ae -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 26
22  UIKit                           0x30e8f68c -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 40
23  UIKit                           0x30e7b11a -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 370
24  UIKit                           0x30e8f102 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 586
25  UIKit                           0x30e8edd4 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 524
26  UIKit                           0x30e89e60 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 828
27  UIKit                           0x30e5f798 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 192
28  UIKit                           0x30e5df9e _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 7094
29  CoreFoundation                  0x2e6b3180 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 12
30  CoreFoundation                  0x2e6b264e __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 202
31  CoreFoundation                  0x2e6b0e42 __CFRunLoopRun + 618
32  CoreFoundation                  0x2e61bc22 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 518
33  CoreFoundation                  0x2e61ba06 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
34  GraphicsServices                0x3330f27e GSEventRunModal + 134
35  UIKit                           0x30ebf044 UIApplicationMain + 1132
36  mobile                  0x00054ae0 main (main.m:16)
37  libdyld.dylib                   0x39386ab4 start + 0

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3942a83c kevent64 + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x3936b210 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 228
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x3936af96 _dispatch_mgr_thread$VARIANT$mp + 34

Thread 2 name:  WebThread
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3942aa8c mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3942a888 mach_msg + 44
2   CoreFoundation                  0x2e6b27be __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 150
3   CoreFoundation                  0x2e6b0ee4 __CFRunLoopRun + 780
4   CoreFoundation                  0x2e61bc22 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 518
5   CoreFoundation                  0x2e61ba06 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
6   WebCore                         0x36829266 RunWebThread(void*) + 414
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x394a5c1a _pthread_body + 138
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x394a5b8a _pthread_start + 98
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x394a3c8c thread_start + 4

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3942aa8c mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3942a888 mach_msg + 44
2   CoreFoundation                  0x2e6b27be __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 150
3   CoreFoundation                  0x2e6b0ee4 __CFRunLoopRun + 780
4   CoreFoundation                  0x2e61bc22 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 518
5   CoreFoundation                  0x2e61ba06 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
6   libAVFAudio.dylib               0x2d69e584 GenericRunLoopThread::Entry(void*) + 124
7   libAVFAudio.dylib               0x2d69299c CAPThread::Entry(CAPThread*) + 176
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x394a5c1a _pthread_body + 138
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x394a5b8a _pthread_start + 98
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x394a3c8c thread_start + 4

Thread 4 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3943d440 select$DARWIN_EXTSN + 20
1   CoreFoundation                  0x2e6b6680 __CFSocketManager + 480
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x394a5c1a _pthread_body + 138
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x394a5b8a _pthread_start + 98
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x394a3c8c thread_start + 4

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3943d440 select$DARWIN_EXTSN + 20
1   ExternalAccessory               0x2eff4352 -[EAInputStream _readInputFromAccThread] + 342
2   Foundation                      0x2f0cbc82 __NSThread__main__ + 1058
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x394a5c1a _pthread_body + 138
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x394a5b8a _pthread_start + 98
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x394a3c8c thread_start + 4

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3942aa8c mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3942a888 mach_msg + 44
2   CoreFoundation                  0x2e6b27be __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 150
3   CoreFoundation                  0x2e6b0ee4 __CFRunLoopRun + 780
4   CoreFoundation                  0x2e61bc22 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 518
5   CoreFoundation                  0x2e65f736 CFRunLoopRun + 94
6   CoreMotion                      0x2ecd2230 ___lldb_unnamed_function1404$$CoreMotion + 724
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x394a5c1a _pthread_body + 138
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x394a5b8a _pthread_start + 98
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x394a3c8c thread_start + 4

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3943dc7c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x394a3dc6 _pthread_wqthread + 306
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x394a3c80 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3943dc7c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x394a3dc6 _pthread_wqthread + 306
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x394a3c80 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3943dc7c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x394a3dc6 _pthread_wqthread + 306
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x394a3c80 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3943dc7c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x394a3dc6 _pthread_wqthread + 306
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x394a3c80 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
    r0: 0x0281f840    r1: 0x31441b29      r2: 0x39647f78      r3: 0x000037f7
    r4: 0x559b030e    r5: 0x39632010      r6: 0x0281f840      r7: 0x27dde5a8
    r8: 0x0281f844    r9: 0x1e2d1f1c     r10: 0x16895960     r11: 0x00000000
    ip: 0x3961f740    sp: 0x27dde568      lr: 0x2e618655      pc: 0x38e79b26
  cpsr: 0x40000030
```

Comment: Turn on zombies in your build scheme and see what object is the message target at the crash point.

Comment: @ Reinhard: No I am not using ARC

Comment: @Phillip: I turned on zombies in your build scheme like, I gave NSDeallocateZombies: YES, NSZombieEnabled:YES. I am not able to get the correct message for object.